# What is CString::StringTraits? What is it for? There seems to be no documentation

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, mfc

Using Visual Studio 2005
As per the title; MSDN and google can't tell me, I'm hoping it'll let me know if the contained string contains Unicode characters or not - but that's a different problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used traits for custom defined comparison function.eg
Currently default comparison implementation of two CStrings is case insensitive.
If you want to do case sensitive comparison between two strings then you can define that behavior in traits.

I am not sure if there are any other use cases.

Comment: But how do we use it? I tried including <cstringt.h> (where it is defined) but the compiler doesn't recognize it.